# Can one get a degree in a field one has not formally taken any classes in?

Tags: coursework, degree, independent-study

If one hadn't taken formally taken any classes relating to a field but was able to demonstrate sufficient competence in the field could one get a degree in that field?

Comment: Do you mean a *honorary degree* like a [*honoris causa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honoris_causa) doctorate?  Depends on what your local school defines as convincing expertise/engagement for your profession/a group ([an example](https://www.ur.umich.edu/update/archives/100319/honorary)) instead of passing written/oral exams.

Comment: How would you display sufficient competence in the field?  How would you have *acquired* sufficient competence in the field?

Comment: I feel like "*relating to a field*" is vague. I know a person who has a PhD in microbiology but has never taken a microbiology course. They have, however, taken courses in molecular biology and biochemistry. Are those classes sufficiently related?

Answer (score 2):

Academically, yes.  The problem is demonstrating you are competent (as judged by the academic unit) in the topics required to get the degree.

In other words, if you can find a school that will let you meet the requirement of all the classes without enrolling in any of these classes, this school *might* let you get a degree.  This is unlikely to be limited to taking final exams in terminal courses since final exams are usually only one component of the final grade.

On the practical side, I doubt university administrators (including academic chairs) will let you get away with something like this.  If anything, they’d probably want the income (or whatever other form of recognition or metric) associated with 4 years of study, so it wouldn’t make much sense to allow people to get degrees without studying in their program (at least in reputable institutions).

One could envisage a scenario where a unit would waive the pre-requisites and invite the student to enrol in upper year courses, thereby requiring the student to complete *some* of the coursework required for the degree but still getting the full degree.  I’ve seen this done once in 25 years (not at my institution), to allow a gifted student straight into graduate school.  However, this cannot be done in every area: you can imagine that in some discipline with labs (for instance chemistry or biology), demonstrating competence in the experimental aspects of the fields is not something can be done so easily.

I must admit that the most common and unfortunate scenario I’ve seen is with  people who *think* they are competent, and dismiss the lack of knowledge in this or that aspect of a discipline as inconsequential.  In other words, people claiming competence in a cherry-picked narrow subfield.

My near-universal experience with such cases is that the claimant are factually rarely competent even in a narrow area.  This is why people asking to get degrees without taking classes are rarely considered seriously, and why administrators are not inclined to waste time on such people.  In all but one of the cases I know, these people were not able to complete the requirements for the degree they sought.